# Extract file from zips in sub folders

Tags: powershell

I'm relatively new to PowerShell and have only been doing "light" scripting to automate a few tasks at work.

Most of the time, I can Google and get the answer(s) I need, with maybe some minor tweaking/experimenting.

But I need some help with this one as I can't find the answer I'm looking so hoping someone here might be able to help me.

DETAILS:

I am provided a directory link on the network drive to either sub-folders containing ".zips" or a folder with ".zips" only.

The latter case works for my current script (will be provided further down) to do it's job but the former is where I'm struggling.

TL;DR - I need the script to go into each folder, extract each ".zip" into a "Temp" folder and then look for a "backup" image file (file type may vary) and then copy it out to the sub-folder and rename to the same as the ".zip" it was extracted from.

Again, my script works if I'm physically in the folder with the ".zip" files but not if the ".zip" files are in sub-folders as I can't get it recursively go into each folder and run the script.

EXAMPLE SETUP:

FolderA\FolderB\1.zip

FolderA\FolderB\2.zip

FolderA\FolderB\3.zip

FolderA\FolderC\1.zip

FolderA\FolderC\1.zip

FolderA\FolderC\1.zip

Script below:

```
#Current Directory of ".zip" files
$fileLocation = read-host "Type/Paste location of creatives"

#replace server path with drive letter
if (Test-Path \\server\path\* -PathType Leaf) {
    $serverPathName = "\\server\path\"
    $driveLetter = "D:\"
    $fileLocation = ($fileLocation -replace [regex]::Escape($serverPathName),$driveLetter)
}
$fileLocation = Resolve-Path $fileLocation
Write-Output $fileLocation

#change directory to the one provided
$zipFilesPath = cd "$fileLocation"
$currentDirectory = pwd

#File type of backup
#Note: `n = new line
write-host "`nChoose Creative Backup File Type"
Write-Host "1. JPG"
Write-host "2. JPEG"
Write-Host "3. PNG"
Write-Host "4. GIF"

$typeFilter = Read-Host "`nType? 1/2/3/4"
if($typeFilter -eq '1'){
    $typeFilter = 'jpg'
}
elseif($typeFilter -eq '2'){
    $typeFilter = 'jpeg'
}
elseif($typeFilter -eq '3'){
    $typeFilter = 'png'
}
elseif($typeFilter -eq '4'){
    $typeFilter = 'gif'
}
else {
    write-host "ERROR! Incorrect Input!"
    Write-Host "Exiting Script..."
    start-sleep -seconds 1.5
    Exit
}

#Files Location
$ZipFilesPath = "$currentDirectory\*.zip"

#Unzip To Same Location
$UnzipPath = "$currentDirectory"

#Check if Temp Folder exists
$TempCheck = Test-Path "$currentDirectory\Temp"

If ($TempCheck -eq $false) {
#Create Temp Folder
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "$currentDirectory\Temp" -Force
}

$TempPath = "$currentDirectory\Temp"

$Shell = New-Object -com Shell.Application
$Location = $Shell.NameSpace($TempPath)
$ZipFiles = Get-Childitem $ZipFilesPath -Recurse -Include *.ZIP

$FileCounter = 1

#Clear Initilisation Vars from Console
clear

foreach ($ZipFile in $ZipFiles) {
    #Get The Base Filename without the extension
    $ZipFileActualName = [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($ZipFile.FullName)

    write-host File:   $ZipFileActualName

    $ZipFolder = $Shell.NameSpace($ZipFile.fullname)
    $Location.Copyhere($ZipFolder.items(), 1040)

    #Find and rename backups

    $BackupFiles = Get-ChildItem $TempPath -Filter *backup*.$typeFilter -Recurse
    $BackupFiles |% {Move-Item $_.Fullname $UnzipPath/$ZipFileActualName'_backup'.$typefilter}

    #Clear Temp Folder
    Get-ChildItem -Path "$currentDirectory\Temp" -Include *.* -File -Recurse | foreach { $_.Delete()}

    #Move Along to Next File
    $FileCounter++
}

#Delete Temp Folder
Remove-Item "$currentDirectory\Temp" -Force -Recurse

#Clear Console
clear
#Read-Host -Prompt “Press Enter to exit”
#start .\
```

I'm open to any suggestions provided or areas of improvement. If I need to completely change the code, I don't mind. Long as it works for both scenarios.

Thanks.

---

**UPDATE**

Modified script as per HAL9256's instruction:

```
#Current Directory of creatives
$fileLocation = read-host "Type/Paste location of creatives"

if (Test-Path \\server\path\* -PathType Leaf) {
    $serverPathName = "\\server\path\"
    $driveLetter = "D:\"
    $fileLocation = ($fileLocation -replace [regex]::Escape($serverPathName),$driveLetter)
}
$fileLocation = Resolve-Path $fileLocation
Write-Output $fileLocation

$zipFilesPath = cd "$fileLocation"
$currentDirectory = pwd

#File type of backup
#Note: `n = new line
write-host "`nChoose Creative Backup File Type"
Write-Host "1. JPG"
Write-host "2. JPEG"
Write-Host "3. PNG"
Write-Host "4. GIF"

$typeFilter = Read-Host "`nType? 1/2/3/4"
if($typeFilter -eq '1'){
    $typeFilter = 'jpg'
}
elseif($typeFilter -eq '2'){
    $typeFilter = 'jpeg'
}
elseif($typeFilter -eq '3'){
    $typeFilter = 'png'
}
elseif($typeFilter -eq '4'){
    $typeFilter = 'gif'
}
else {
    write-host "ERROR! Incorrect Input!"
    Write-Host "Exiting Script..."
    start-sleep -seconds 1.5
    Exit
}

#Files Location
$ZipFilesPath = "$currentDirectory"

#Unzip To Same Location
$UnzipPath = "$currentDirectory"

#Check if Temp Folder exists
$TempCheck = Test-Path "$currentDirectory\Temp"

If ($TempCheck -eq $false) {
#Create Temp Folder
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "$currentDirectory\Temp" -Force
}

$TempPath = "$currentDirectory\Temp"

$Shell = New-Object -com Shell.Application
$Location = $Shell.NameSpace($TempPath)
$ZipFiles = Get-Childitem $ZipFilesPath -Recurse -Include *.ZIP

$FileCounter = 1

#Clear Initilisation Vars from Console
clear

foreach ($ZipFile in $ZipFiles) {
    #Get The Base Filename without the extension
    $ZipFileActualName = [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($ZipFile.FullName)

    write-host File:   $ZipFileActualName

    $ZipFolder = $Shell.NameSpace($ZipFile.fullname)
    $Location.Copyhere($ZipFolder.items(), 1040)

    #Find and rename backups

    $BackupFiles = Get-ChildItem $TempPath -Filter *backup*.$typeFilter -Recurse
    $BackupFiles |% {Move-Item $_.Fullname $upzipPath/$ZipFileActualName'_backup'.$typefilter}

    #Clear Temp Folder
    Get-ChildItem -Path "$currentDirectory\Temp" -Include *.* -File -Recurse | foreach { $_.Delete()}

    #Move Along to Next File
    $FileCounter++
}

#Delete Temp Folder
Remove-Item "$currentDirectory\Temp" -Force -Recurse

#Clear Console
clear
#Read-Host -Prompt “Press Enter to exit”
#start .\
```

That did what I need to do. But how can I modify my script so it stores the backups in their respective folder? So the backups extracted from "FolderB" stay in "FolderB", etc? Is there something I can do?

---

**UPDATE 2**
Final code - Thanks to help from HAL9256:

```
#Current Directory of creatives
$fileLocation = read-host "Type/Paste location of creatives"

if (Test-Path \\server\path\* -PathType Leaf) {
    $serverPathName = "\\server\path\"
    $driveLetter = "D:\"
    $fileLocation = ($fileLocation -replace [regex]::Escape($serverPathName),$driveLetter)
}
$fileLocation = Resolve-Path $fileLocation
Write-Output $fileLocation

$zipFilesPath = cd "$fileLocation"
$currentDirectory = pwd

#File type of backup
#Note: `n = new line
write-host "`nChoose Creative Backup File Type"
Write-Host "1. JPG"
Write-host "2. JPEG"
Write-Host "3. PNG"
Write-Host "4. GIF"

$typeFilter = Read-Host "`nType? 1/2/3/4"
if($typeFilter -eq '1'){
    $typeFilter = 'jpg'
}
elseif($typeFilter -eq '2'){
    $typeFilter = 'jpeg'
}
elseif($typeFilter -eq '3'){
    $typeFilter = 'png'
}
elseif($typeFilter -eq '4'){
    $typeFilter = 'gif'
}
else {
    write-host "ERROR! Incorrect Input!"
    Write-Host "Exiting Script..."
    start-sleep -seconds 1.5
    Exit
}

#Files Location
$ZipFilesPath = "$currentDirectory"

#Unzip To Same Location
$UnzipPath = "$currentDirectory"

#Check if Temp Folder exists
$TempCheck = Test-Path "$currentDirectory\Temp"

If ($TempCheck -eq $false) {
#Create Temp Folder
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "$currentDirectory\Temp" -Force
}

$TempPath = "$currentDirectory\Temp"

$Shell = New-Object -com Shell.Application
$Location = $Shell.NameSpace($TempPath)
$ZipFiles = Get-Childitem $ZipFilesPath -Recurse -Include *.ZIP

$FileCounter = 1

#Clear Initilisation Vars from Console
clear

foreach ($ZipFile in $ZipFiles) {
    #Get The Base Filename without the extension
    $ZipFileActualName = [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($ZipFile.FullName)

    write-host File:   $ZipFileActualName

    $ZipFolder = $Shell.NameSpace($ZipFile.fullname)
    $Location.Copyhere($ZipFolder.items(), 1040)
    $DestinationDir = $ZipFile.DirectoryName.Replace($ZipFilesPath,$unzipPath)

    #Find and rename backups
    $BackupFiles = Get-ChildItem $TempPath -Filter *backup*.$typeFilter -Recurse
    $BackupFiles |% {Move-Item $_.Fullname $DestinationDir/$ZipFileActualName'_backup'.$typefilter}

    #Clear Temp Folder
    Get-ChildItem -Path "$currentDirectory\Temp" -Include *.* -File -Recurse | foreach { $_.Delete()}

    #Move Along to Next File
    $FileCounter++
}

#Delete Temp Folder
Remove-Item "$currentDirectory\Temp" -Force -Recurse

#Clear Console
clear
#Read-Host -Prompt “Press Enter to exit”
#start .\
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify the path:

```
#Files Location
$ZipFilesPath = "$currentDirectory\*.zip"
```

Then trying to get the  files:

```
$ZipFiles = Get-Childitem $ZipFilesPath -Recurse -Include *.ZIP
```

What you essentially are saying is `Get-Childitem` and get *only* `*.zip` ***files***. Because the path parameter has the wildcard filter, it will only get all the `*.zip` files in that directory and will not get any *folders*. Since you have no folders matching the `*.zip` wildcard, `Get-Childitem` won't have any folders to continue to recurse through.

The solution is to only give a base folder to the path parameter for the `Get-Childitem` to recurse through, and, correctly, use the `-Include` to apply the filter for the type. e.g.:

```
#Files Location
$ZipFilesPath = "$currentDirectory"

...

$ZipFiles = Get-Childitem $ZipFilesPath -Recurse -Include *.ZIP
```

---

**EDIT:**

To move the file to the same folder structure, when inside the loop, you simply use the replace function to replace the source Directory path (the first part of the Directory Name) with your destination base path. Then the sub folders will remain the same. e.g.

```
...

$DestinationDir = $ZipFile.DirectoryName.Replace($ZipFilesPath,$upzipPath)

...

$BackupFiles |% {Move-Item $_.Fullname $DestinationDir/$ZipFileActualName'_backup'.$typefilter}
```

Comment: Hi Hal9256,
Thanks for the help. That did what I need to do.
But how can I modify my script so it stores the backups in their respective folder?
So the backups extracted from "FolderB" stay in "FolderB", etc?

Is there something I can do?

Comment: When you move the files you can simply text replace the source directory with the destination directory. Please see edits above.